# Configure incoming connection (VPN) on Microsoft Hyper-V 2008 via command line

Tags: vpn, command-line-interface, hyper-v

In both Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 (R2), it is extremely easy to allow incoming connections (VPN). Just go to overview of network adapters, click 'file' and click 'new incoming connection'.

Hyper-V 2008 however, does not have any GUIs. Is it possible to configure this via the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can do it using the command Rasdial.

Thought i recommend you to configure the VPN using a Group Policy. You can see the procedure here: [Configure a Virtual Private Network Connection Item](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772449.aspx)